# SVN commit messages are not getting updated

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have updated some of SVN commit messages using below command:

```
svn propset --revprop -r $version --force svn:log " $logMsg "
```

But, in SVN GUI the "show log" option still displays old commit messages. And one interesting fact I noticed is that when I try to edit the commit message using "Edit log message" option I could see the updated messages in the pop-up window.

I tried "refresh" option available in SVN GUI to get the updated commit messages; but didn't work.

I need help to make the updated commit messages to be displayed in GUI [show log option].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that TSVN can use some cache for data fetched from repository. There is no hash or timestamp in SVN API to check if some commits changed so the only option to find out that if recop has changed is to get it from the repo.
Try to use TSVN->Settings->Saved_Dat to clear all caches.

Comment: Thank you Kamil :)
I had cleared the Cached Repositories from Log Caching under SVN settings and now it's working perfect.